# cron command with a date suffix?

Tags: unix, cron

In the commandline I am able to do

`cp htlog.out test.$(date '+%m%d%Y')`

but when I try to crontab it like this:

```
37 17 * * 1-5 cd the/dir && cp htlog.out test.$(date "+%m%d%Y")
```

It fails with the following message from the CRON DAEMON:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

And I do have endlines after the command. What is wrong with that crontab entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` in `crontab` have a special meaning, it should be *backslashed*, so:

```
37 17 * * 1-5 cd the/dir && cp htlog.out test.$(date "+\%m\%d\%Y")
```

From `man 5 crontab` :

> A "%" character in the command, unless escaped  with  a  backslash
>   *       (), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.